# Can you switch into Single User Mode Without Rebooting?

Tags: macos, shell, shell-script

Is it possible to switch into single user mode WITHOUT rebooting and holding CMD+S.
For example, can I write a shell script to switch into single user mode? 
If so, for which operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear so, for any BSD-like OS.  I did find [this article which suggests a way to move between modes (in FreeBSD) if started from Single User Mode](http://www.geekvenue.net/chucktips/jason/chuck/1021225962/index_html).  However, note that even via this method, the multi-user system has to effectively shut down before returning in single user mode.  This may work on a Mac, but I can't test it effectively myself due to a screen resolution problem when I boot into single-user mode, which obscures much of the console window.  All articles I've seen referencing single-user mode on Mac OS X include holding <kbd>cmd-S</kbd> after rebooting.  Furthermore, the manpages for `launchd`, the process that manages runlevel configuration, and `launchctl`, the program that interfaces with `launchd`, make no mention of single-user mode.

The BSD command I've seen referenced to reboot into single-user mode, `nextboot`, does not appear to exist in Mac OS X.